# Jenkins dynamic GIT BRANCH option parameter

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I want to know if it's possible to **list** from a dropdown the GIT branches that are inside my repo dynamically on Jenkins, what I mean by this is if I currently have 3 branches (master/stage/dev) I want them to show on the dropdown when executing the job, but if tomorrow I add a new one, I want that new one to show without me to go and add the new option.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you check - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin ?

you just need to add a git parameter  , and a new dropdown will appear.

Comment: yes thank you! that plugin does exactly what I want!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it with a `Active Choices Reactive Parameter` Jenkins Plugin.

Step 1: You need to first **install a plugin for Jenkins**.

1. Open Jenkins Dashboard
2. Click `Manage Jenkins`
3. Go to `Manage Plugins`
4. Under `Available` tab search for `Active Choices Plug-in`

Step 2: After Plugin is installed, **add a parameter to your pipeline**

1. Go to your pipeline
2. --> Configure --> General
3. Find Setting `This project is parameterised` and click it if not active yet
4. Click `Add Parameter` and choose `Active choices reactive parameter`
5. Give the parameter a name (e.g. BRANCH)
6. Choose `Groovy Script` and add the following script as it is (only changing the link to your repo)

   def gettags = ("git ls-remote -t -h git@github.com:YOUR_REPO.git").execute()
   return gettags.text.readLines().collect {
   it.split()[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gt4mm.png).replaceAll('refs/heads/', '').replaceAll('refs/tags/','').replaceAll("\^\{\}", '')
   }

You're done!

[image]